# Read from Oracle AQ Error Queue

Tags: oracle, jms, message-queue, weblogic12c

I want to write the size of the AQ Error Queue to my WebGUI.

I, of course, can figure out the size of the normal queue by creating a connection with the connection factory. However, this connection is not intended get hints about the error queue, isn't?

If there is a chance to abuse this established session (connection to regular queue) to grab the total size of the error queue, how would I do that? I prefere to use an EJB.

- If not, I would have to get the JMS database user from the DBA and then read out the queue size from there.
- Alternatively, could I do that with MBeans, too?

I rather would go the other way around and use the connection factory (session).

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You may (if you can) do a regular `select` on the exception queue. For an exception queue there's always a regular table in your DB.

For info on AQ's exception queues please refer to the [Oracle AQ documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADQUE/jm_create.htm#ADQUE2927).

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have DB-read access, and are limited to consume messages only, to an (Oracle Advanced) queue, you cold:

1. fetch the message from a queue
2. increment an index with every message you fetch fromthe queueue
3. rollback after the index has been incremented.

This way you don't consume the messages but are able to count it.

I WANT TO MAKE THIS CLEAR: THIS IS A WORK AROUND! If you have not been granted read access to the advanced queuing database! Also this approach does not work out well, if the queue is stacking-up or is consumed quickly. The size-number is timely less accurate than when invoking `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MYADVANCEDQUEUE`.

I certainly DONT recommend this if you have a straight-forward solution.